# Highlight similar sub html inside the source html page

Tags: java, html, analytics, highlight, similarity

I have 2 HTML pages
1. A complete HTML page. Let's call this source page
2. A small HTML page(sub page) which is similar to a small part of source page.

Example

**Source page**

```
<div>
This is a source page
</div>
```

**Sub page**

```
<div>
This is blank page
</div>
```

Here we have a sub page which is similar to source page.
It might not be entirely inside the source page. It means the sub page might not be exactly a substring of source page but some parts of sub page and source page would be intersecting.

I need to highlight the **sub page** inside the **source page**.

I was thinking about using the graph to find the similarity between words(nodes) and finding the start and end nodes in source page.
This is not concrete but only a thought.

Any suggestion/implementation would be helpful.
I am using Java for implementation.

Comment: "It might not be entirely inside the source page." what does that even mean?

Comment: It means the sub page might not be exactly a substring of source page but some parts of sub page and source page would be intersecting.

Comment: So write that, and show an example. It is very hard to understand your question as it is now

Comment: Use a Java `diff` utility, and use it's output as constraints for creating a starting and ending index for your highlight procedure.